# Import data from an external sql server database into local database using php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a website where I query one of our external sql servers and insert the records into the local server of the website.

I'm simply connecting to the external database, querying the table, truncating the local table, and running a foreach to insert data into the local table.

The process works fine, the problem is that it takes a long time.

I just want to see if you guys could give me some hints on how to speed up the process. If there is another way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Take a look at sql server replication.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I have to use PHP for this process because we have other members who log in to the website with special permissions and need to run this import from the website

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question is too broad and not appropriate for the Stack Overflow format.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many factors to determine the best approach. Is the database you are copying to supposed to always be the same as the source one, or will it have entries that are not in the source one. If you just want them to be identical, and the web site database is simply a read only clone, you have a bunch of ways in SQL Server to do this: replication, log shipping, mirroring, SSIS packages. It all depends on how frequently you want to synchronize the databases and a lot of other factors.

Comment: We have a view that gets data from multiple tables. That view is identical to the table in the web server database table. The import process has to be done from the website admin panel. Because we have multiple employees with different permissions, some of those employees needs to click the import button to import changes when they are confirmed. So I'm trying to find out if anyone has a better PHP approach on importing data from external databases

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your needs right, but if an import is started when someone requests it, that same transfer of data could be done automatically when it is confirmed on the source side. If you are trying to keep two databases completely in sync then you handle that at the server level. If you want the second database to be somehow different from the source database and only include what is requested to be imported, then you have to write a php function to just read what you want and insert it into the destination tables. That's just simple php data queries.